# SpringBoot webapp under Java SecurityManager throws exceptions when granted AllPermission

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

We have a Spring Boot (1.1.6) application deployed as a .war file to a Tomcat 7.0.52 / OpenJDK 7 server.  We need to run this server under a SecurityManager.

Even when we operate the server with a policy that allows AllPermission to all code (essentially the same as *not* running under a SecurityManager) we get exceptions thrown due to reflection activity.  Here's a full stack trace of one of the exceptions.

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Class org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1 can not access a member of class org.springframework.boot.context.web.ErrorPageFilter with modifiers "public"
    at sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(Reflection.java:109) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.slowCheckMemberAccess(AccessibleObject.java:261) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.AccessibleObject.checkAccess(AccessibleObject.java:253) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:599) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:277) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil$1.run(SecurityUtil.java:274) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.52]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAsPrivileged(Subject.java:536) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.execute(SecurityUtil.java:309) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.security.SecurityUtil.doAsPrivilege(SecurityUtil.java:249) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:237) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.access$000(ApplicationFilterChain.java:55) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:191) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain$1.run(ApplicationFilterChain.java:187) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.52]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:186) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220) ~[catalina.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteIpValve.invoke(RemoteIpValve.java:683) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
    at ch.qos.logback.access.tomcat.LogbackValve.invoke(LogbackValve.java:178) [logback-access-1.0.13.jar:na]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408) [catalina.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.52]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313) [tomcat-coyote.jar:7.0.52]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_65]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_65]
```

The policy file which is applied to the server is shown below:

```
grant { 
  permission java.security.AllPermission;
  permission java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission "suppressAccessChecks";
};
```

.. we added the explicit `ReflectPermission` just in case `AllPermission` didn't include it but we tried it both ways.

Any pointers as to why the exception gets thrown only when we run under a SecurityManager with the above policy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is caused not by Java Security, but by Java Language access rules.

The ErrorPageFilter class is package-visible [1]. Tomcat tries to call public method of that class via reflection, but cannot because by Java Language rules the class itself is not accessible.

[1] https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/context/web/ErrorPageFilter.java

(I am linking to master branch, but you are actually using version 1.1.6, so content of the above link may change over time)

A non-public Filter is unusual. In old times when all filters were declared in web.xml it was not possible to use such non-public filters. I do not know Spring Boot internals, but I guess that this filter was added to the web application programmatically, using Servlet 3.0 APIs.

Possible ways to proceed:

a) Ask Spring Boot developers to make the class public

b) Change Apache Tomcat so that instead of looking for method declared by specific class it were looking for method declared by specific interface. A java.lang.reflect.Method declared by interface can be invoked on a class implementing that interface. I expect that this solution will pass those checks in sun.reflect.Reflection.ensureMemberAccess(), but actual testing is needed.

This needs changing internal Tomcat APIs to pass the interface class (in this case, javax.servlet.Filter) as an additional argument to those methods.

Technically, this needs:

- File an issue into Tomcat Bugzilla - DONE.
- Provide a simple reproduction recipe, so that this can be tested
- Wait for the next release

**Update:** I filed this into Bugzilla,
https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57281

Comment: yes.. understood and thanks for the response.  But the question is why does this behaviour only appear when the JVM has an *active* security manager (regardless of policy)?  This class appears to be accessible when there is no SecurityManager and inaccessible when there is.

Comment: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/tomcat/tc7.0.x/tags/TOMCAT_7_0_52/java/org/apache/catalina/core/ApplicationFilterChain.java?view=markup    Line 237-238 versus Line 241.  A method of Filter interface can be called. A method of specific class cannot.

Comment: got it.. thanks very much.  I've additionally queried the visibility of the class on the SpringBoot github page where a similar issue was discussed a few months ago: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/933

Comment: SpringBoot issue raised too: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2026